# Python: numpy.interp giving curved line

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I'm trying to linearly interpolate a low resolution curve (10 data points) to a much higher resolution (~1000 data points). What I would like is a new curve of the same shape but with many more x and y values, i.e. the high and low resolution curves would look indistinguishable when plotted as lines.

I've used Numpy's interpolation many times so this baffles me. I do the usual `np.interp(newX, oldX, oldY)` but I'm getting a funny result when I plot it.

[image: Not linear interpolation]

The lines between the green squares should be straight, not arched like this.

I'm not sure if it matters but my X values range from 0 to 1000 and my Y values range from 1e-12 to 1e-16. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: The above plot was log log scale but it happens on a linear plot too.

[image: Linear plot, same problem!]

Here's the actual data. (It's really 1e-15 to 1e-19):

```
X = array([  0.3543  ,   0.477   ,   0.544579,   0.6231  ,   0.64142 ,
         0.7625  ,   0.79788 ,   0.9134  ,   1.02894 ,   1.235   ,
         1.241608,   1.615118,   1.662   ,   2.159   ,   2.181858,
         3.4     ,   3.507511,   3.732206,   4.436578,   4.6     ,
         4.664426,   5.628102,   7.589159,  12.      ])

Y = array([  8.54633502e-19,   3.82388943e-18,   7.33750003e-18,
         2.98683733e-17,   7.77237551e-17,   2.04059657e-16,
         3.72124584e-16,   8.77407275e-16,   1.65824812e-15,
         2.48616026e-15,   2.80165491e-15,   2.03270375e-15,
         2.03205199e-15,   1.24592352e-15,   1.20231667e-15,
         3.85565084e-16,   4.34827044e-16,   3.86967563e-16,
         1.67622220e-16,   1.48774069e-16,   1.25065750e-16,
         7.53511540e-17,   2.34138998e-17,   5.77852724e-18])
```

So I am convinced that it is indeed just a log scale effect. For some reason though, when I plot it using `ax.loglog()` and then do `ax.set_yscale('linear')` the axis scale changes but the subplot data doesn't. When I plot it using `ax.plot()` it seems fine.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I haven't thought this through fully, but because your numbers are so small, maybe there's some floating point precision effects going on.  i.e. you're taking the difference of very small numbers which leads to significant loss of precision.  What is the datatype (`float32` or `float64`)?  What happens if you re-scale your inputs to be closer to 1, interpolate and then rescale back down?

Comment: `np.interp` converts all its inputs to `NPY_DOUBLE`, see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/src/_compiled_base.c#L599), so I don't think 4 orders of magnitude should be an issue.

Comment: Could you show the plotting code?

Comment: why not try numpy.percentile?

Comment: can you post the values of x and y so that I can try to find if numpy.percentile would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this same issue as well but with scipy's interpolate.interp1d.  The issue is not with the code, but with how logarithms work.  Straight lines on a linear plot become curved lines on a semilog plot.  Consider the limiting case where you have only two points *(ya,xa)* and *(yb,xb)* you want to plot on a semilog plot and connect.  If you first do a linear interpolation between these points, you create an object which is a line segment *L(x)* (represented by say, an array of finely gridded points).  If you then take the log of *L* and plot it vs. *x*, you'll get a curved line.  This is what gives the "bouncy" behavior on your attached plot.  If you want a straight line in the log plot, you'll need to take the log of *ya* and *yb*, interpolate, then plot. If you're looking at something that spans multiple decades, you'll probably want to interpolate after taking the log, but it may depend on your application.

Answer (score 2):

Translated from http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,1000,10)
y = np.random.uniform(1e-16, 1e-12, 10)
xvals = np.linspace(0, 1000, 100)
yinterp = np.interp(xvals, x, y)

plt.plot(x, y, c='k')
plt.plot(xvals, yinterp, 'o', c='w')
plt.show()
```

[image]